# Unexplained paramiko error

Tags: python

When using ssh with paramiko to execute the command on remote system. When executing it gives error

```
def execute(self,command):
            to_exec = self.transport.open_session()
            to_exec.exec_command(command)
            stdout.write("\r%s" % "Executed")
            stdout.flush()

get_connection.execute('sh /etc/botclient/avail_pack.sh')
```

---

```
File "/home/xxx/project/server/ssh_module.py", line 43, in execute
    to_exec = self.transport.open_session()
AttributeError: ssh_connection instance has no attribute 'transport'
```

Comment: You will need to explain your question better. Perhaps give some background to your problem.

Comment: The error comes from your self object (a ssh_connection object) not having a transport attribute. The information is kind of there in the what you've just posted.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't got a `Transport` stream object. Maybe try creating one with `self.transport = self.get_transport()` like this:

```
def execute(self,command):
        self.transport = self.get_transport()
        to_exec = self.transport.open_session()
        to_exec.exec_command(command)
        stdout.write("\r%s" % "Executed")
        stdout.flush()

get_connection.execute('sh /etc/botclient/avail_pack.sh')
```

Though if that doesn't work you'll have to give us some more information.